# Why are std::allocator::construct and std::allocator::destroy templated on element type?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocation, allocator

`std::allocator`'s `construct` and `destroy` member functions are parameterized on the type of the element to construct:

```
template<class T>
  class allocator
{
  public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T* pointer;

    template<class U, class... Args>
      void construct(U *p, Args&&... args);

    template<class U>
      void destroy(U *p);

  ...
};
```

What's the rationale for this? Why don't they take either `value_type*` or `pointer`? It seems like `allocator<T>` should only know how to construct or destroy objects of type `T`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's for the same reason that `allocator`s are required to have the `rebind<U>` typedef: because many containers never allocate `T`s.

Take linked lists. These allocate nodes, each one of which *contains* a `T` as a member. So `allocator`s are required to be able to allocate some type that they don't know of (via `rebind<U>`). However, that requires a copy operation: it requires creating a new allocator of the type `rebind<U>::other`.

It's better to avoid that when possible. Therefore, for construction and destruction, allocators are required to do the appropriate operations on any type, such as the linked list's internal node types. This also makes it possible for the linked list's internal node type to have `Allocator::construct/destruct` as friend functions.